# Facebook like button loads only once

Tags: javascript, facebook, event-handling, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've added facebook like button, but it works only once on the page. The page consists of "tiles" and every tile has own link and user should be able to "like" any tile on the page. The code of the called function is the following:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', handleResponse(response));

var handleResponse = function(response) {
    var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="some_url_goes_here"');
    query.wait(function(rows) {
        alert('number of likes ' + rows[0].like_count);
        // ... other code
    });
};
```

When user presses some button - appears Facebook "like" button (e.i. called function startFacebook(), the content of which is given above) together with like buttons of some other social networks.

Some time ago the contents of this function started with:

```
FB.Event.clear('edge.create');
```

but this is deprecated now and Facebook says that is should not be used any more and sends response like this:

```
c   jssdk_error
m   {"error":"Private method used","extra":{"args":"Event.clear"},"appId":"246731078776510"}
```

When I used FB.Event.clear - everything worked fine. Does anyone knows how to substitute this lacking funciton?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to remove the event listener?
If so, then use [FB.Event.unsubscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.unsubscribe/) just like you used `FB.Event.subscribe`:

```
var handleResponse = function(response) {
    ...
}

FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", handleResponse);

...

FB.Event.unsubscribe("edge.create", handleResponse);
```

Comment: Just unsubscribing does not solve he problem. I think that I need somehow to "clear" everything relating to FB so that FB looks like as if it was just initialized. Is there some other way to do that not using FB.Event.clear?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? Why do you want to "clear" everything?

Comment: I tried to initialize FB a few times in every function and for every tile and it works somehow, but in console i get message "FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem".

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is why you want to re-init the sdk? Is it matter of using the like button for different urls?

Comment: Actually, I did now want to reinit it, but that is the only way (for some reason) to make it work almost the way I need (except of "FB.init has already been called..."). If I init FB only once globally - than only the first function I call works properly. Every function is unique, has its own handler, writes own cookies, makes some ajax requests etc and works with different urls. E.g., function startFacebook_124() {... sets some necessary flags, subscribe event, sets handler, adds button iframe ...}. If i reinit FB locally in this function - everything works but gives error I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please explain what it is you are trying to do?